# 404 on LiteSpeed vhost

Tags: litespeed

I just installed OpenLiteSpeed 1.6.17 on my dedicated server running Debian 10, with the goal to replace my Apache 2.4.38 in the future.

I have access to OpenLiteSpeed WebUI, didn't changed the default HTTP listening port 8088 for now as I'm waiting for everything to run smoothly before switching to 80 and removing Apache.
I started to create a vhost with the OpenLiteSpeed webUI, with the following:

```
Virtual Host Name: www.example.com
Virtual Host Root: /home/www/production/example.com
Config file: $SERVER_ROOT/conf/vhosts/example.com/vhconf.conf
Document Root:  $VH_ROOT
Use Server Index Files: Yes
```

But, when I try to access `http://www.example.com:8088`, I get a 404, obviously served by LiteSpeed.

What did I forget?

More info:

- I use the webUI to create the vhosts to be sure, but it successfully creates the file in `/usr/local/lsws/conf/vhosts/example.com/vhost.conf`
- The general settings says index files are index.html and index.php so there shouldn't be an issue about the index file (which is `/home/www/production/example.com/index.html`).
- The virtual host root is still owned by Apache user `www-data` but I made sure LiteSpeed user `lsadmn` is part of `www-data` Linux group.
- The specific log for this vhost is created, but empty, as if there has been no access to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you map the vhost to domain in Listener ?

Comment: I didn't! That was that. Thanks!